# What do taxiway lane, taxiway strip and taxiway shoulder mean?

Tags: terminology, ground-operations, taxiing

I am developing a game which involves an airport simulation. And I am looking into the general rules that traffic control has for busy airports and am also confused on the terminology of a taxiway.

According to ICAO taxiway widths have 3 types of labeling which is as follows:

```
Taxiway Lane
Taxiway Strip
Taxiway Shoulder
```

What is the taxiway shoulder? I am fairly sure the lane is the 2 outer yellow lines from the center  taxiway line right? And the strip is the entire taxiway width, but I am unclear on the shoulder label? I could not find an image that showed what this was.

Comment: Your last paragraph should be a separate question,  if [this similar question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/7552/control-responsibility-for-an-aircraft-on-the-ground-lies-with) doesn't cover it.

Comment: @fooot i'm not sure it does answer it, it doesn't explain which gets priority - the departing plane from jetways etc or the plane already on the move on the taxiways. Unless theres no logical priority and is decided in the moment by traffic control.

Comment: Priority is usually given to aircraft ready to taxi, before other aircraft are cleared for pushback. This might be overruled by slot assignments, if the plane pushing back has a significantly earlier slot to make and would need to be sequenced in front of the other aircraft anyway. Too many factors to logically disseminate this.

Comment: @Dave I've trimmed your second question about pushback priority because none of the answers below really address it, and it should be a logically separate question anyway. If you ask it as a separate question we can try to get you some answers :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Skybrary from EUROCONTROL](http://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Taxiway_Surface_Markings_and_Signs) and a UK CAA document on taxiways markings ([Visual Aids Handbook UK CAA CAP 637 (2007)](http://www.skybrary.aero/bookshelf/books/291.pdf)), the definitions are:

*Taxiway Strip*

An area which contains the taxiway and gives protection to aircraft from obstacles and other taxiways.

[image: TaxiStrip]
<sup>Image Source: Transport Canada</sup>

*Taxiway Lane*

This one is ambiguous and could not be found citation on, except for a [document from the BAZL](http://www.bazl.admin.ch/dokumentation/grundlagen/02643/02644/index.html?download=NHzLpZeg7t,lnp6I0NTU042l2Z6ln1acy4Zn4Z2qZpnO2Yuq2Z6gpJCDe318g2ym162epYbg2c_JjKbNoKSn6A--&lang=de). Taxilanes or Taxiway Lanes are dashed taxiways, which give guidance to stands and aircraft parking positions.

*Taxiway Shoulder*

The taxiway shoulder is the paved or unpaved area beyond the double taxiway edge line, indicating that the load bearing capabilities beyond these lines can be different from the taxiway weight allowance.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Section 3. Airport Marking Aids and Signs](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim/aim0203.html) of the FAA's AIM and [AIRPORT SIGN AND MARKING – QUICK REFERENCE GUIDE](https://www.faa.gov/airports/runway_safety/publications/media/QuickReferenceGuideProof8.pdf)

Comment: Good info, the first link seems to be broken now though.